# Getting captcha image generated by javascript on client side

Tags: javascript, ruby, captcha

I tried to get captcha image using Nokogiri, hpricot but instead of image I've got javascript that generates captcha. How can get captha image build by javascript?

Page: https://kavkazsg.megafon.ru/

Firewatir doesn't suit this task cause application will be used in console

Answer (score 1):

The Image is not generated by javascript, it's loaded via an Ajax request.

A Captcha on the client side (e.g. pure javascript) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have `Bitmap` apis, so it won't be able to generate a captcha.

Also whats the point to doing it in the client side since the whole logic of captcha generation will "open source"!